# Sitecore Access rights for a custom role not behaving as i expected

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, rights

I am having trouble with setting the secutrity rights for the Media Library of one of our customers. For the "Sitecore Client Authoring" role I have specifed that it has only read access for the entire Media Library. I needed to "unprotect" items to do this but the Access Viewer tells I have succeeded.
Subsequently I wanted to specify access rights for a custom role. That custom role is a member of the following roles:

- sitecore\Sitecore Client Forms Author
- sitecore\Sitecore Client AccountManaging
- sitecore\Sitecore ClientAuthoring
- sitecore\Author
- sitecore\Sitecore Marketeer Form Author

The problem is that the Access Viewer keeps telling me (when I look at the access rights for that custom role) that my custom role has write rights on Directory A because the sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring account has been granted the 'item:write' access right for the '/sitecore/media library' item. When I look at the sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring role in the Access Viewer the system tells me a different story. There the sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring role only has read rights.

This is the basic structure of the Media Library for this customer.

**Media Library**

- Files

  - Directory A
  - Directory B
  - Directory C
    etc.
- Images

  - Directory A'
  - Directory B'
  - Directory C'
    etc.

Any idea why the write access rights are granted to my custom role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try to reset the cache(/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx). If it's the 6.X issue, the access result is not resetted in time, so the wrong result keeps available in the cache.

Answer (score 2):

Try iisreset and take a look at Access Viewer again. Does it reflect the situation correctly now?

It seems there was an issue in some older versions of SC 6.X.

Comment: You could also try to reset the cache(/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx). If it's the 6.X issue, the access result is not resetted in time, so the wrong result keeps available in the cache.

Comment: @Alex: Could you write the thing you just said here as an answer so i can accept it please? @Yan: Thanks for the suggestion again!